# how only this element textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this

I have this js code, and that's work on all `textarea` in site, i want that's work only on one element

```
function limits(obj, limit) {
    var text = $(obj).val();
    var str_length = $(obj).val().length;
    if (str_length > limit) {
        $(obj).val(text.substr(0, limit));
        $('span.limite').html(limit - str_length + ' znaków!');
        $(obj).addClass('limit');

    } else {
        $('span.limite').html((limit - str_length) + ' pozostało znaków!');

        //
    }
}


$(document).on('keyup', 'textarea.thisArea', function() {
```

This is my html

```
<textarea class="thisArea" name="post_content[146][content]"></textarea>
```

All `textarea` have another `postcontent`

Comment: use an id instead of a class

Comment: If it's for one textarea only, use an ID?

Comment: This is why it's important to understand the source code you're using, rather than using anything just because it appears to be working. A basic understanding will make things easier if you wish to modify existing source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `script` for this

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#selector', function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    var str_length = $(this).val().length;
    if (str_length > limit) {
        $(this).val(text.substr(0, limit));
        $('span.limite').html(limit - str_length + ' znaków!');
        $(this).addClass('limit');

    } else {
        $('span.limite').html((limit - str_length) + ' pozostało znaków!');
    }
})  

<textarea id="selector" class="thisArea" name="post_content[146][content]"></textarea>
```